# How to merge two .MTS files in Linux

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two video files from a Panasonic camera in .MTS format and I want to merge them into one file and burn that file onto a TV-playable DVD.

I tried importing them into kino and merging them, but the resulting file has somehow a very slow video playback and the audio is way out of sync.

I selected the MPEG tab with file format '8 - DVD' with no deinterlacing.

Can someone point me into the right direction for merging the two files correctly?  Since exporting of the file takes around one hour, it's quite impractical to play around with different options :)

Comment: Isn't kino for DV only? If `ffmpeg` can handle it, you could use `ffmpeg -i 'concat:1.mts|2.mts' output.mpeg` (plus whatever codec/quality options you desire).

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better match for SuperUser?

Answer (score 1):

```bash
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    # Join video clips

    video1="$1"
    video2="$2"

    name="${video%.*}"
    ext="${video#*.}"

    (( $# != 2)) && printf "%s\n" "Pass two videos to convert" && exit 1

    read -p "Name of joined file? " jfile

    ffmpeg -i "$1" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts int_1.ts
    ffmpeg -i "$2" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts int_2.ts


    ffmpeg -i "concat:int_1.ts|int_2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "$jfile"

    (( $? == 0 )) && rm int_*

    # vim:set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 et:
```